# Creating HTTP Handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httphandler

can anyone tell me how to create Custom Hander (.ashx) file.
Requirement: When a request come to my application for a .pdf, I want to invoke that .ashx handler. The .ashx handler will have logic to show the file or not.

My incoming path would be "http://www.domainname.com/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf".
This URL should be handled by a "http://www.domainname.com/Handler.ashx" file.

I would like to know how to create, map, and register the handler in my application

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need an `HTTPHandler` if you are working with ASP.NET MVC, Use an `Action` method to server your file content. You can do most of the things you do with an `HttpHandler` in an Action method. You can do the routing of the action as you wish like  `http://domainname.com/content/abc` can return the abc.pdf file

You should not directly let the browser to access the resource (PDF). Instead you give access via an `action` method. Read the file Id /name in the action method from the request and read the file and output it. Assuming that you have an action method like below in your `ResourceController`

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string id)
{
   string fullFilePath=somefullpathvariable+"//"+id+".pdf";
   return File(fullFilePath, "application/pdf", Server.UrlEncode(id+".pdf"));
}
```

Now users can access this like

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/Resource/awesomemvc
```

Now this can return a file called `awesomemvc.pdf` from a location which is stored in your server and your `someFullPathVariable` holds the path to that location

Comment: i initially opted for mvc routing solution only. But!!, my url "http://www.domainname.com/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf" directly gets executed and doesnt go through route defined.

routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapRoute("PDFRoute", "Content/PDF/{id}", new { controller = "User", action = "GetPdf", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

Comment: @shakti: It will go thru if you are exposing it via an action method. See my updated answer.

Comment: Please understand my requirement:
In Google Search my application url shows up. I want that url to be accessible only to logged in customers.

The url is http://www.domainname.com/Content/PDF/ABC.pdf
(with .pdf, extension)

Now i want to route that to my controller and action.

For that i have coded.
routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
routes.MapRoute("PDF","Content/PDF/{id}",new { controller = "User", action = "GetPdf" });

Then too the pdf file directly gets opened up without going though my defined route. The same code i have added in my sample project and it works over there.(strange!!!)